# CSS, div to be not affected by any other div?

Tags: css, html, tinymce

I am asking that because tinymce menus are going too up or down. I have TinyMCE(that is a javascript plugin). And when i click for example on file menu it is going 100-200px up or down from the textarea(which is transformed with javascript with options) everty time is different, one time is with 100px up, other is 200px down. That are my css settings to the div:

```
.post {
width:100%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
overflow:auto;
margin-top:20px;
max-height: 249px;
z-index:999999999;
}
.my_div textarea{
overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: Please provide more context. Your problem is not understandable.

Comment: I have TinyMCE(that is a javascript plugin). And when i click for example on file menu it is going 100-200px up or down from the textarea(which is transformed with javascript with options) everty time is different, one time is with 100px up, other is 200px down.

Comment: That are my css settings to the div:
.post {
 width:100%;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto; overflow:auto;
 margin-top:20px;
        max-height: 249px;
 z-index:999999999;
}

.my_div textarea {
    overflow:auto;
}

Comment: Can you edit your original question to include that information you just added in the comments? Your original post should contain all this information, to make it easier to help you!

Comment: I've added it before a hour. Can anyone answer me?

Comment: What is the purpose of the random z-index? It doesn't do anything!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've just downloaded new version of TinyMCE and all is ok.